# Sklearn: ValueError: X and Y have incompatible shapes

Tags: scikit-learn

I am new to sklearn and in general to python as well. Can you help me figure out if this script is leading to some solution? Basically I am using an hue extractor on an Imageset: load iset for training, extract features, define classifier and then classify.

```
    #load beach for training
iset = ImageSet('/Users/Arenzky/Desktop/img_dirs/supervised/beach/') #load Image database

hue = HueHistogramFeatureExtractor() # define extractor
edge = EdgeHistogramFeatureExtractor()
x = []
y = []
for b in iset:
    ...:        x.append(hue.extract(b))

hset = ImageSet('/dir/.../h01/') 
hue = HueHistogramFeatureExtractor() # define extractor
edge = EdgeHistogramFeatureExtractor()
for h01 in hset:
    ...:        y.append(hue.extract(h01))

dataset = np.array(x)
targets = np.array(y)

print 'Training Machine Learning'
clf = LinearSVC()
clf = clf.fit(x, y)
clf2 = LogisticRegression().fit(x, y)

#predict
```

...
after loading clf I get:

```
ValueError: 
X and Y have incompatible shapes. X has 20 samples, but Y has 286.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is pretty explicit: you have 20 samples (rows) in your input datasets and 286 labels hence the mismatch. Each sample should be labeled once hence `y.shape[0]` should be equal to `x.shape[0]`. I don't know how your feature extractors work (and you did not put the import lines but by googling it's from SimpleCV). Please refer to the documentation of this module to understand the nature of their output and how to transform them to something that satisfy the sklearn shapes assumptions.

Comment: Ok, indeed the 20 samples are basically 20 images from a ImageSet, the 286 labels are from applying the hue.extractor() on the imageSet. So let me reformulate the issue: Besides the ImageSet, I have another 5 images in a folder named "fakeimages". Now, I want to compare/classify the 5 images in the fakeimages dataset according to the extracted hue values from ImageSet. Can you provide me a suggestion/pathway to follow based on sklearn?

Comment: You need 20 feature / descriptor vectors for each of the 20 images to classify along with 20 target label, one for each of the picture to classify. I don't know Hue Histogram features so I cannot give more specific advice. Labels are target categories integer indices for your classifier.

BTW machine learning algorithm will most probably lead to crappy results on a training with just 20 examples. I would recommend collecting at least labeled 100 images per target class. So you if you have two classes (e.g. "pedestrian" vs "background") I would recommend labeling at the very least 200 pictures.